# Как ускорить создание проекта на PHPRunner при подключении к базе данных Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, оптимизация

Имеется база данных Oracle 8 на удаленном сервере с объемом данных ~ 300 GB. На локальном ПК использую клиент Oracle 11.2 версии, Apache 2.4.20 и PHP 5.6.26.
При создании нового проекта программой PHPRunner и соединения с базой данных Oracle возникает проблема в очень долгом создании проекта, а также в любых дальнейших действиях, связанных с задействованием таблиц базы данных (например, банальное "снятие" галочки с таблицы). Загрузка достигает около 50 минут для каждого действия.

Как я теперь понимаю, основных проблемы могут быть две:

1. Создавая новый проект на PHPRunner, я подключаюсь под админом, который видит все таблицы во всей БД. А мне необходимо создать пользователя, который будет видеть только несколько нужных для проекта таблиц и не видеть всей "архитектуры" БД... Пока не нашел решение этой проблемы...
2. Неправильно настроенный клиент Оракла 11.2 (я просто скачал архив и распаковал на диск "C", указав path в системных настройках Windows 7.

Comment: Соединение действительно устанавливается через около 50 мин.? А если клиентом попробовать соединится?

Comment: @0xdb Я пробовал подключаться через SQLDeveloper и напрямую через php (написал маленький скрипт на локальном веб сервере) - подключается моментально.
Вопрос ещё в чём: на текущем месте работы все опытные работники ушли и спросить не у кого ... Ранее (не мной) был установлен SQLDeveloper, через который исправно работает подключение к БД, но для PHP или Python клиент не подходил - происходила ошибка (по-моему нестыковка x86 или x64).
После я скачал клиент для оракла 11.2 и через него стал подключать php и python - работает ок.

Comment: @0xdb как я сейчас понял - подключение происходит быстро, но вопрос в "индексации" или как правильно назвать подобные действия PHPRunner, т.е. когда нажимаю на "Создать Проект" - начинается подключение и программа "зависает" на ~ 50 минут. При этом в новый проект погружаются все таблицы базы данных, а их большое количество и поэтому и зависает.... 
Для аналогии я попробовал установить аналогичную программу - PHPMaker, которая при настройке подключения просит указать одно поле "Schema" - и если я указываю "Схему", в которой, например, 1 таблица - PHPMaker создает проект моментально...

Comment: @0xdb Поэтому теперь вопрос, наверно, можно задать иначе:
Ранее я подключался через PHPRunner пользователем, который видит все таблицы всей базы данных, т.е. грубо говоря под админом.... А теперь мне нужно создать пользователя, который будет видеть только несколько нужных для проекта таблиц.... Но при создании такого пользователя - а далее при создании проекта всё равно прогружаются все таблицы всей БД.. =(
Я создаю пользователя через SQLDeveloper и, видимо, что-то делаю не так, поэтому всё равно создаваемый проект на PHPRunner "тянет" все таблицы.... Пока не могу найти решение.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При переходе на СУБД Oracle 11.2.0.4 проблема решилась.